# Second order to first order equations

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to write

$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} + 4\sqrt{k}\,\frac{d\theta}{dt}+g\sin(\theta)=0$$

as a first order equation.

What I have done so far is:

Let $z = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$
Then $z' = \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$

Therefore the second order equation can be written as

$$z' + z +g\sin(\theta) = 0)$$

But I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: its not $z'+4\sqrt{k}z+g\sin\theta=0$? what happened to the factor $4\sqrt{k}$?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake when typing it, I meant $z' + 4\sqrt{k}z + gsin(\theta) = 0$

Answer (score 3):

Let  $a=4\sqrt k$
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} + a\frac{d\theta}{dt}+g\sin(\theta)=0$$
Change of function : $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=z(\theta)$

Do not confuse with $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=z(t)$ which fails to reduce the order of the ODE.

$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{dz}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=z\frac{dz}{d\theta}$

$$z\frac{dz}{d\theta} + a\:z+g\sin(\theta)=0$$
Let  $z=\frac{1}{y(\theta)}$
$$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=a\:y^2+g\sin(\theta)\:y^3$$
This is an Abel's differential equation of the "non-solvable" kind, in the sens of "with a finite number of elementary and/or standard special functions".

That means : There is no hope to find a closed form for the solutions.

Numerical methods and/or judicious physical approximation have to be considered to further progress.